# Register route 404 not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes

I am building a register page and when I submit the I am getting a 404 not found. I am using react and express and I think the front end is good. I am missing some back end or have the wrong url for my post request: axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth'. Would appreciate some advice if anyone can see what I have wrong.

```
     const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = {
          username: username,
          password: password,

        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', { user })
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          })
      }
```

This is the registerPost function for my route.

```
export const registerPost = async (req, res) => {
    
    const {username, password} =  req.body;
    
    const newUser = new User({username, password});

    try {
        await newUser.save();
        console.log(newUser);

        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }


}
```

These are the routes.

```
import express from 'express';

import { getPosts } from '../controllers/posts.js'
import { createPost, updatePost, deletePost, registerPost } from '../controllers/posts.js'

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getPosts);
router.post('/', createPost);
router.patch('/:id', updatePost);
router.delete('/:id', deletePost);
router.post('/auth', registerPost);

export default router;
```

Comment: What port are you using to run your express app? And in your request you're using {user} I think it should be only user.

Comment: My express app is on http://localhost:5000/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a 404 error, which means the url you're trying to reach does not exist. In the React app, you're sending the request at `http://localhost:5000/`, but in the Express app, you've defined the register route as `/auth`.

Updating the url in the React app to `http://localhost:5000/auth` should fix this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you're passing the following Object from the Frontend:

```js
{ user: { username, password } }
```

but in the backend you're not looking for the `user` property, but directly for the username and password.

```js
const {username, password} = req.body
// =>
const { user } = req.body
```